# Angular UI-Router: How to call child state without its parent?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-router-extras

We have recently move our application to Ui-Router from ng-route. And we are trying to refactor some points in our code regarding routing.

We have a list view and a detail view in our application. The detail view will be shown as a pop-up on top of the list view, so in order not to initialize all list controller logic again and again, we have defined our detail view as a child view-state. It looks like this:

```
  $stateProvider
    .state('list',
      {
        url: "/",
        template: '<list-directive></list-directive>'
      })
    .state('list.detail',
      {
        url: "/detail/{item_id}",
        template: '<detail-directive></detail-directive>'
      })
```

It actually works as expected. When i open a detail view from a list view, the list view (i mean the controller) does not run again, and when i close the detail view, the list view remains.

But now we would also like to call the detail view DIRECTLY, **without revoking the parent**. Currently when i directly call the detail state, the parent controller runs also.. How can i achieve this?

Is a parent - child relationship not a appropriate one for our scenario?

Comment: did you tryed to add your controller to your state definition ? BTW why to use child state if there is no loink between the two states ?

Comment: @Abhijeet it does not work that way.. i want my parent to be activated itself

Comment: @DMCISSOKHO We are adding our directives to our state definitions, not controllers.. controllers are defined in directives. But i dont think it does have sth. to do with that too.. About your 2. question: it is exactly why i ask here.. "should i use parent- child relationship?"..

Answer (score 0):

According ui-router doc :

> Child states can be used to drill down from a more general feature to
>   more specific one, or to implement a master/detail pattern. (...) The child state’s view usually renders inside a viewport that the parent state created. This is referred to as Nested Views (...) **These substates share the common parent state contacts and inherit data and behavior from the parent.**

So I think you should use it if you don't want these behaviour .

Comment: We got this, by defining a new state for this case.. so you also call the same component-view directly but in that case it behaves like a parent itself..

Answer (score 0):

It did work like this:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('list',
      {
        url: "/",
        template: '<list-directive></list-directive>'
      })
     .state('detail',
      {
        url: "/detail/{item_id}",
        template: '<detail-directive></detail-directive>'
      })
    .state('list.detail',
      {
        url: "detail/{item_id}",
        template: '<detail-directive></detail-directive>'
      })
```

But the angular is very fragile.. and behaves very different with very small changes.. the slashes are the problem.

Child state list.detail does not have a leading slash in its URL. But our new state detail (which has exctly the same content as the list.detail) should have a leading slash so it can be called directly. So We have the same state both as child and as parent.

Now when we call directly the URL "host/detail/5" we go to detail view without revoking the parent. And we we call ui-sref=".detail(5)" we go to child state (list.detail) within the parent